# Can we implement AWS-Appsync ina project without using GraphQL?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

Can I implement AWS-Appsync without the use of GraphQl, Project's front end is based on Angular and by using Socket i'm getting the backend data stored in Database. I wanted to implement AWS-Appsync without any usage of GraphQL

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me more about your use case? AppSync is a graphql managed service so you can't use it without graphql. What are you trying to accomplish with AppSync?